# Is it possible to have the "do not disturb" function in Asterisk time out?

Tags: asterisk

As I saw some Asterisk love on here when I did a quick search, thought I'd ask if anyone knows of a way to have the "do not disturb" function on an asterisk phone time out after say 5 minutes.

In our call centre, we get phones put on do not disturb, then have them minimised and "forgotten" about, so I would love to be able to put a time limit on this function.

Did some digging, but didn't turn anything up.  Any ideas?

Using tribox if that's any consideration.

Thanks.

Peter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press DND on a phone no signal (SIP message) is sent to Asterisk, it only sets a local DND state on the phone (please reject all my calls). Therefor, there is no way you can timeout a DND from Asterisk. As stated before, it should be a feature found on the phone (I do not know any phone that will do that dough)

What you can do is tell if a phone is on DND status after dialing into it, as it should answer with a

```
Got SIP response 480 "Do Not Disturb" back from xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
```

In that way, you can find out if an extension is set to DND and take some measure on it after dialing into it.

By the way, DND should be prohibited by law on a callcenter :-)

Answer (score 1):

That's going to be a feature of the softphone you're using rather than asterisk itself (unless you're dialling a code to activate DND).